# Python: "TypeError: Could not operate with block values" coming when I import RandomForestClassifier

Tags: python, pandas, machine-learning, scikit-learn, random-forest

I am writing a digit recognition program in python. The basic code is as follows:

```
import pandas as pd
from sklearn.ensemble import RandomForestClassifier
filteredColumns = delete_useless_columns()
train = pd.read_csv('C:\\Users\\abchauhan\\Downloads\\train.csv')
trainData = train.loc[0:24998, filteredColumns]
target = train['label']
targetData = target[0:24999]
rf = RandomForestClassifier(n_estimators=150, min_samples_split=2, n_jobs=-1)
x = trainData/255 #Feature scaling
print('Fitting the data')
rf.fit(x, targetData)
```

The feature scaling line gives the error: `TypeError: Could not operate 255 with block values`. Now if I remove the `RandomForestClassifier` import statement the feature scaling works fine, but obviously then the program is of no use. Why is the division working without the import statement?

Edit: 
`trainData.info()` is as follows:

```
<class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'>
Int64Index: 24999 entries, 0 to 24998
Columns: 708 entries, pixel12 to pixel779
dtypes: int64(708)
memory usage: 135.2 MB
None
```

Stack Trace is as follows:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
 File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\pandas-0.15.2-py3.4-win32.egg\pandas\core\internals.py", line 965, in eval
result = get_result(other)
 File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\pandas-0.15.2-py3.4-win32.egg\pandas\core\internals.py", line 949, in get_result
return self._try_coerce_result(func(values, other))
 File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\pandas-0.15.2-py3.4-win32.egg\pandas\core\ops.py", line 765, in na_op
op, str_rep, x, y, raise_on_error=True, **eval_kwargs)
 File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\pandas-0.15.2-py3.4-win32.egg\pandas\computation\expressions.py", line 218, in evaluate
**eval_kwargs)
 File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\pandas-0.15.2-py3.4-win32.egg\pandas\computation\expressions.py", line 71, in _evaluate_standard
return op(a, b)
 MemoryError

 During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

 Traceback (most recent call last):
 File        "C:/Users/abchauhan/PycharmProjects/DigitRecognition/PreProcess/RandomForest.py", line 20, in <module>
 x = trainData/255
 File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\pandas-0.15.2-py3.4-win32.egg\pandas\core\ops.py", line 831, in f
return self._combine_const(other, na_op)
 File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\pandas-0.15.2-py3.4-win32.egg\pandas\core\frame.py", line 3111, in _combine_const
new_data = self._data.eval(func=func, other=other, raise_on_error=raise_on_error)
 File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\pandas-0.15.2-py3.4-win32.egg\pandas\core\internals.py", line 2478, in eval
return self.apply('eval', **kwargs)
 File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\pandas-0.15.2-py3.4-win32.egg\pandas\core\internals.py", line 2457, in apply
applied = getattr(b, f)(**kwargs)
 File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\pandas-0.15.2-py3.4-win32.egg\pandas\core\internals.py", line 972, in eval
result = handle_error()
 File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\pandas-0.15.2-py3.4-win32.egg\pandas\core\internals.py", line 956, in handle_error
% (repr(other), str(detail)))
 TypeError: Could not operate 255 with block values 

 Process finished with exit code 1
```

Comment: Can you post data to reproduce this error, also what is the output from `df.info()` and `trainData.info()`

Comment: Added trainData.info(). df was not used so removed it. Data is a matrix of numbers ranging from 0 to 255.

Comment: Can you post some code that reproduces this error?

Comment: I have already posted the code. It gives TypeError on dividing trainData/255. If I remove the import statement of RandomForestClassifier and its consequent code, the division goes through without any error.

Answer (score 0):

This is a memory error, as indicated by the first error in your stack trace.